# Why does my extension method cause a type error?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I have the following Playground code:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

extension Array {
    func toHexString<CUnsignedChar>() -> String {
        var returnString = NSMutableString(capacity: self.count * 2)
        for i in self {
            let val = i as Int // if someone would like to answer why casting this as a CUnsignedChar throws an error, I'd appreciate it -- but that's a separate question
            returnString.appendFormat("%02X", val)
        }
        return returnString
    }
}

var hashedString: String? {
    get {
        let x: CUnsignedChar[] = [0xA, 0xB, 0xC]
        return x.toHexString()
    }
}

println(hashedString)
```

This causes the error, "NSString is not a subtype of 'String'"

However, if I rewrite this code to be:

```
var hashedString: String? {
    get {
        let x: CUnsignedChar[] = [0xA, 0xB, 0xC]
        var returnString = NSMutableString(capacity: x.count * 2)
        for i in x {
            returnString.appendFormat("%02X", i)
        }
        return returnString
    }
}

println(hashedString)
```

I get no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things I would recommend.

First, use `UInt8` instead of `CUnsignedChar` for an array of bytes. Also, I would stay away from `NSMutableString` and use standard string concatenation and interpolation via Swift. I have not had much success trying to use `CVarArgs` inside Swift.

Here is my implementation:

```
extension Array
{
    func toHexString() -> String
    {
        var hexString = ""

        for value in self
        {
            if let integerValue = value as? UInt8
            {
                let stringValue = String(integerValue, radix: 16)

                if integerValue < 0x10
                    { hexString += "0\(stringValue)" }
                else
                    { hexString += stringValue }
            }
        }

        return hexString;
    }
}

let arrayOfBytes : Array<UInt8> = [ 0x0A, 0x13, 0x02, 0x2F, 0x22, 0x7A, 0xF1 ]

let hash = arrayOfBytes.toHexString()
let hashUppercase = hash.uppercaseString
```

It is unfortunate that you cannot create an `extension` solely for `Array<UInt8>` and must extend all `Arrays`, even if your method is only valid for one type.

Comment: I was using `CUnsignedChar` because I was using some CommonCrypto hashing functions elsewhere which calls for a `CMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>` (even though CUnsignedChar is a type alias I wanted to match the function prototype). It's kind of unfortunate that `String` doesn't have any formatting method, but like you said working with `CVarArgs` in Swift is pretty weird at the moment. I noticed I had to do strange type casting to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that your extension does not return an optional, but your hashedString does.

However, the playground crashes like crazy when I try to mess around with the above code. =)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but I did try it to make sure. It has no affect. Quick edit to this comment: I tried it but didn't realize I wasn't actually using the extension in my playground. Crashes like crazy when I make it optional as well.